# Pass function call from a class to one of its members based on another member parameter

Tags: c++, class, templates, call, function-call

Assume I have the following `class A` which is passed around through different function calls and wrappers.

```
class A{
std::vector<int> a;
public:
int getSize const {return a.size();}
int getVal(int i) const {return a[i];}
// other private and public members and functions 
}
```

Now for some reason I need the same class but with a double vector. I cannot templatize this class, because there are many function signatures that I cannot change. What is suggested is to rename `A` to `A0`, templatize that, create new `A` containing `A0<int>`, and `A0<double>` as follows:

```
template <typename T>
class A0{
std::vector<T> a;
public:
int getSize const {return a.size();}
T getVal(int i) const {return a[i];}
// other private and public members and functions 
}

class A{
// only one of the following will be initialized in the constructor and the other one will be null.
std::shared_ptr<A0<int>> iA;
std::shared_ptr<A0<double>> dA;
// also the following flag will be set in the constructor
bool isInt;
}
```

This is the question: If I want to make minimum changes in different places of the code that previously accessed, changed, or just passed around the instances of class `A`, what shall be done? For example, consider this in a different part of the old code:

```
A x;
int n = x.getSize();
```

Is there a way to keep that old code without implementing a method `getSize()` inside the new `A` class that would contain an if-conditional statement and return either `iA->getSize()` or `dA->getSize()` based on `isInt`? Is there a smart way to do this?

Is there any other suggestions for achieving the goal of minimum modifications in different parts of the code that use (mostly pass around) the old `A`?

}

Comment: What type do you expect e.g. `getVal` to return without breaking previous code relying on it to be `int`?

Comment: Of course this is not the real code, but in such places, it would be handled specifically for each case. Mostly this class is only passed from one method to another until it reaches the method where the real action is done (and things can be handled for each case there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is only about passing on the object (or a reference to it) and not actually using any member of the object, then you can simply use a `std::variant`:

```
using A = std::variant<A0<int>, A0<double>>;
```

At the point where members are actually used, use `std::visit` to determine the type and act on it.

---

If passing happens only by-reference, then making the `A` an empty base class of `A0<T>` will also work. You can then cast back to the real type using `static_cast<A0<int>&>(...)` or `static_cast<A0<double>&>(...)` to use the members at the destination. You *must* however assure that you cast to the actual type of the passed object, otherwise you have undefined behavior.

An alternative is `dynamic_cast` instead of `static_cast`, which will throw or return a null pointer if the types don't match. But that requires the base class `A` to have a virtual method to be polymorphic.

Comment: Is it possible to make A a base class for A0, while A0 is used inside A?

Comment: @KuroshMotamedian What does "*used*" mean here? It is not clear what your question is aiming at.

Comment: I mean members of A are shared pointers to type A0. Is the following possible?class A{
B b;
//...
};

class B:public A{
//...
};

Comment: @KuroshMotamedian In neither of my two suggestions does `A` have any user-specified members. Did you mix up `A` and `A0`? My second suggestion assumes that `A` is some empty base, so that the derived `A0<T>` can be passed as reference to `A`, but only be used after `static_cast`ing back to `A0<T>`. This does however (in contrast to the first solution), that the target knows apriori whether the passed `A&` is really referencing a `A0<int>` or `A0<double>`. If you cast to the wrong one, you will have UB. An alternative is `dynamic_cast`, but then `A` must be polymorphic, i.e. have a virtual func

Comment: @KuroshMotamedian See update in my answer for important details.

Comment: Thank you for the really helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

`std::variant` might be what you need. Create a `buffer` class and forward all the container operations to it. There is no need to change too much in your class `A`, but you should mimic `std::vector<T>` in `buffer`, i implemented `size()` and `const subscript operator`. Here is the basic demonstration.

```
#include <variant>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct store_as_int {};
struct store_as_double {};

class buffer {
    public:
        buffer( store_as_int ) : data { std::vector<int>{} } {
            std::cout << "I am storing numbers as int" << std::endl;
        }
        buffer( store_as_double ) : data { std::vector<double>{} } {
            std::cout << "I am storing numbers as double" << std::endl;
        }

        [[nodiscard]] std::size_t size() const noexcept {
            std::size_t s;
            std::visit( [ &s ]( auto&& arg ) {
               s = arg.size(); 
            } , data );

            return s;
        }

        [[nodiscard]] double operator[]( std::size_t idx ) const {
            double s;
            std::visit( [ &s , idx ]( auto&& arg ) {
               s = arg[ idx ]; 
            } , data );

            return s;
        }

    private:
        std::variant< std::vector<int> , std::vector<double> > data;
};

class A{
    buffer a;
public:
    A() : a { store_as_int{} } {}
    A( store_as_double ) : a { store_as_double {} } {   }
    int getSize() const { return a.size(); }
    int getVal(int i) const { return a[i]; }
};

int main()
{
    A x;
    A y { store_as_double{} };
    int n = x.getSize();
    int t = x.getSize();

    std::cout << n << std::endl;
    std::cout << t << std::endl;
}
```

Output :

> I am storing numbers as int
>   I am storing numbers as double
>   0
>   0

[run online](https://onlinegdb.com/rk01vJNEU)